# How to trim String in Java

Tags: java

I have a string:

Am trying to do the below :

```
int i =0;

for(String s : appFields){
    i++;
    String divid = "chart_"+i;
    divid = divid.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+$", "");
}
```

I would like to trim it so that the value is only `chart_1` and so on.

Can someone help me please?

```
<%
    String[] appFields = "Account Information,Action Status,Activity Name,Activity Status,Last Activity Timestamp,Geographical Region,Enterprise Status,Business Process,Numer of Pages,Message Direction".split(",");

    int i =0;

    for(String s : appFields){
        i++;
        String divid = "chart_"+i;
        divid = divid.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+$", "");
%>
<tr>
    <td><% out.println(i); %></td>
    <td><% out.println(s); %></td>
    <td class='with-3d-shadow with-transitions'><p><svg id="<% out.println(divid); %>" class="sparkline"></svg></p></td>
</tr>
<% 
    }
%>
```

This is the output i get in Chrome Web Inspector

```
<td class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"><p><svg id="chart_1
" class="sparkline"></svg></p></td>
```

Comment: That's not a valid `String` literal if it appears on multiple lines.

Comment: there's a trim fnc yes?

Comment: @ZouZou Trim doesnt work!

Comment: @Bosko Are you sure the edit of putting the `"` on the same line was valid?

Comment: @user3176143 Then show a short program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: int i =0;
                         
                         for(String s : appFields){
                           i++;
                           String divid = "chart_"+i;
                           divid = divid.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+$", "");
}

Am getting string in the above format while i try to do the above.

Comment: There isn't any space there?

Comment: @user3176143 Likely you are using it as `temp.trim()`, which will not modify the current string as Strings are immutable. Try with `temp = temp.trim()` and it will work.

Comment: @MathiasMuller you edited away the issue the op was talking about...

Comment: I don't think I did that. Look at the edit history first.

Comment: @user3176143 Can you [edit] your short example into the question? It's difficult to read in the comment because formatting is lost.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I did that before commenting.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with `trim` but the string `"strngval"` cannot be trimmed anymore because it has no leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: The original questions was about another string: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21189535/4 
Can somebody restore this?

Comment: @assylias: No, look again. The post was edited many times before I did.

Comment: @thegrinner edited the question. do you get my problem now ?

Comment: @user3176143 To clarify: [edit] the question so the original case remains and just use your second example to expand on it.

Comment: the new version of the question makes no sense: 's' is never referenced, and you create a string without crud at the end, then ask how to remove the crud at the end? The original question seemed to be asking how to remove trailing whitespace, including a newline, to which .trim() is the right answer.

Comment: Your example doesn't show any need for trimming. What do **you** mean by trimming?

Comment: Please run the code in any of your local machines and then give your solution. trim() doesnt work

Comment: @user3176143 _"trim() doesnt work"_ Show your attempt using `trim()` with an example of input/output.

Comment: Since your string only contains `chart_` and a number, there is no spaces to remove.  trim() shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close. After all of this you still haven't told us what you are expecting and what you are getting.

Comment: @ZouZou I wouldneed a reputation of 10 to post images. this doesnt allow

Comment: Why do you need an image? Just post it with text. It's a `String` after all.

Comment: @user3176143 Why post images? Post your actual code as text.

Comment: I have posted the actual code.. Can anybody please help now

Comment: Answers anybody ? Please run it in your machine and answer

Comment: Now when i posted the actual code and output why is anybody not replying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line to

```
<svg id="<%out.print(divid);%> " class="sparkline"></svg>
```

In other words, use `print` instead of `println`. `println` adds a new line after your `String`.

Comment: Wonderful! Worked. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ShabeerMothi Note that it makes no different in a browser. The browser typically trims any whitespace anyway.

Comment: Sure. but am just wondering why people marked my question as irrelevant and voted it one down!

Comment: @ShabeerMothi Because we got tired of not getting relevant information from you. You should always try to provide as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score 6):

```
temp = temp.trim();
```

`String`s are immutable so operations return new `String`s that you have to assign back to the original reference variable.

Comment: I edited the question sir. Can you please help me with the issue am facing.

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant.